# How can I differentiate between product creation and saving existing products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer

I want to create an observer that will execute some code when a new product is added. However, it seems that `catalog_product_save_before`, `catalog_product_save_after` and `catalog_product_save_commit_after` will all fire when an existing product is being saved. Is there an event that will fire exclusively for new products or alternatively a way to differentiate between an existing product being saved and a new one being created with the previously mentioned events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to rely on `$product->isObjectNew()`, this gets set in `_beforeSave` before the event `catalog_product_save_before` is triggered. It essentially performs a check on whether `$product->getId()` has a value before save is called and persists that value for the life of the object within that request.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. This works fine for `catalog_product_save_before` but doesn't persist for the other events. Is this the only event where you can differentiate or can it be done with the others too?

Comment: Whilst I haven't actually tested it, since `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave` calls `->isObjectNew(true)` which sets a protected property to true before triggering the `_save_before` event, the `_save_after` and `_save_commit_after` events passed the same instance should also return true for `$product->isObjectNew()`, since this favours the cache variable over `->getId()`.

Comment: @browndesk965 Did you ever get this to work outside of `catalog_product_save_before`?  `isObjectNew()` is true in `save_before`, but not in `save_after` every time I try.

Answer (score 4):

For me the `isObjectNew()` was available in `catalog_product_save_before`, but was not available in `catalog_product_save_after`.  I simply created my own `isNew` variable in the Observer and set it to true in `beforeSave` and checked it in the `afterSave` methods.

```
<?php
class Some_Module_Model_Observer
{
    protected $isNew = false;
    public function beforeSave($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
            $this->isNew = true;
        }
    }

    public function afterSave($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($this->isNew) {
            /*Add Logic Here*/
        }
    }
}
```