# event observer for the creation of new products

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I want to run the observer only when the product is created and not when it is updated. I found this [discussion](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53915/how-can-i-differentiate-between-): product-creation-and-saving-existing-products and I followed Tim Ramsey's advice.

So I put this in the config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <wally_logproductupdate>
            <class>Wally_LogProductUpdate_Model</class>
        </wally_logproductupdate>
    </models>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <wally_logproductupdate>
                    <class>wally_logproductupdate/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeSave</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </wally_logproductupdate>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

and this in Observer.php:

```
class Wally_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer
{
    protected $isNew = false;

    public function beforeSave($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
            $this->isNew = true;
        }
    }

    public function afterSave($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($this->isNew) {
            $name = $product->getName();
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $price = $product->getPrice();

            Mage::log("[{$name} ({$sku}) {$price}] aggiornato", null, 'product-updates.log');           
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the log file is not updated when a new product is created.

How can i solve?

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: My magento version is 1.9.3.9

Comment: log file will not create because `afterSave` function never called! you need to call `$this->afterSave();`  after check `isNew`.

Comment: @Pawan I tried your advice and got this error Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Wally_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer::afterSave()    Maybe I have to change public function afterSave($observer) in public function afterSave($product)?

Comment: you need to pass `$observer` as parameter  like `$this->afterSave($observer);`

Comment: you can also eliminate ` $this->isNew = true;` flag and direct call `$this->afterSave($observer);` in if condition!

Comment: It works!! thanks a lot @Pawan

Comment: glad to know @Mastafis, I have put my comment as answer. you can upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log file will not create because `afterSave` function never called! 
you need to call `$this->afterSave($observer);` after check `isNew`.

Like:

```
public function beforeSave($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
        $this->afterSave($observer);
    }
}
```

**Note:** you can also eliminate `$this->isNew = true;` flag and direct call `$this->afterSave($observer);` in if condition!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SR_MagentoCommunity>
            <version>0.0.0.2</version>
        </SR_MagentoCommunity>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sr_magentocommunity>
                <class>SR_MagentoCommunity_Model</class>
            </sr_magentocommunity>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <sr_catalog_product_save_before>
                        <class>sr_magentocommunity/observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductSaveBefore</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </sr_catalog_product_save_before>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <sr_catalog_product_save_after>
                        <class>sr_magentocommunity/observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductSaveAfter</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </sr_catalog_product_save_after>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class SR_MagentoCommunity_Model_Observer
{
    protected $isNew = false;

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function catalogProductSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
            $this->isNew = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function catalogProductSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($this->isNew) {
            $name = $product->getName();
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $price = $product->getPrice();
            error_log("[{$name} ({$sku}) {$price}] aggiornato");
            Mage::log("[{$name} ({$sku}) {$price}] aggiornato", null, 'product-updates.log');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```